# Android: Google-Map doesn't work with Phonegap

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

Iam trying to get Android's Google-Map.api to work with Phonegap. I can't figure out the problem though. I tried everything so far. Please check my code. I do not get any errors and I also included jQueryMobile. Apologies for a messy code.

Index.html:
-including all kind of stuff-

Google.html:

```
   <body>
<div data-role="page" id="foo" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="googlemap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var map = new GoogleMap();
        map.initialize();
    }
</script>
```

googlemap.js is the same as seen in this tutorial:
[christianengvall.se](http://www.christianengvall.se/phonegap-and-google-maps/)

The anchor hypertext reference to Google.html includes a ref="external" attribut. I don't know if it is important or not.

I also added the whitelists in res/xml/cordova.xml (up-2-date?)

My manifest file has all permissions android probably has. (temporarily)

When I run/debug this page on a real device (Samsung Galaxy S3) I get a white screen.

A possible problem could be the data-role attribut of Google.html. Maybe there is something like data-role="mapload".

If you need further information please ask me.

//Edit

It still doesnt work. I found another solution though which is a big mess. If somebody is able to upload a good code please go for it

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be fine *that is if you've got CSS right*, disable the scripts, and add to the CSS file:

```
#map_canvas {background: red;}
```

Do you see the red box? If not, then give it a height, `height: 100%` is a good height in jquerymobile if you do not use a footer as it flows above the content (headers are OK). If you do use a footer and want 100% height, go with `$("#map_content").css("height", ($("*[data-rel=content]").height()-$("*[data-rel=footer]").height())+"px");`

Some other pointers:

If you're having problems, try `adb logcat` (there is a window in eclipse for that if you dislike the terminal), it can give you some pointers.

The attribute `rel=external` is irrelevant as far as i know.

The whitelist i am using is:

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->

<access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="http://gstatic.com" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="https://google.com" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="https://gstatic.com" subdomains="true"/>
```

Comment: i'm having the same problem, but i see the red box, what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible problem: did you copy

```
function onBodyLoad(){      
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

From the [the example](https://github.com/crilleengvall/Phonegap-GoogleMap-and-ProjectSettings-example/blob/master/www/index.html)?